# Black “grille” after stereographic projection+rotation

Tags: projection

When I do a stereographic projection and rotationX of omnidirectionnel image, I get this image: [image]

My question is why I get that "grille" in the image, it appears only when I add rotation

Comment: Missing interpolation and spatial aliasing? It seems like you're mapping the original pixels like a set of individual points, which will tear apart the image and allow the background to shine through. On top you're drawing the pixels on the nearest integer position, which generates that beautiful moiré pattern you are seeing. In short: Your image rendering method is far less than optimal.

Comment: Yes I solve that with interpolation, but what I want to know is the name of the phenomena and if it is common to have that problem using stereographic projection+rotation @Jazzmaniac